# What is a "(UIView) -> CGFloat"? I am trying to get a CGFloat value

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, cgfloat

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollPositionY(view:UIView) -> CGFloat {
        if let origin = view.superview {
            // Get the Y position of your child view
            let childStartPoint = origin.convert(view.frame.origin, to: self)

            let this = childStartPoint.y

            return this
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
let theYvalue = theScrollView.scrollPositionY
```

`theYvalue` is of type `(UIView) -> CGFloat`

Can I convert this to a CGFloat?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the function. Functions are called using `()`, and because you have parameters, arguments need to be passed in, like `(view: someViewPassedIn)` where `someViewPassedIn` must be of type `UIView`.

In Swift, the difference between functions and closures is very small. Variables can be set as a closure, which is what `(UIView) -> CGFloat` is. It is a closure that has not been called like a function.

It can be quite hard to wrap your head around, but basically closures contain the block of code between the curly brackets/braces, `{}`, and the `()` runs that block of code.

Instead of:

```
let theYvalue = theScrollView.scrollPositionY
```

Try:

```
let theYvalue = theScrollView.scrollPositionY(view: someViewPassedIn)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let theYvalue = theScrollView.scrollPositionY
```

Just assigns the function to theYvalue

I think what you want is

```
let theYvalue = theScrollView.scrollPositionY()
```

which evaluates the function and should be a CGFloat, which the function returns.